# Getting Volume Name from Device Path in USB devices

Tags: c++, windows, usb, media, insertion

I've built a program using the Windows API that detects the insertion of some media (cd, usb...). The program returns the device path:

`\\\\?\\usb#vid_vvvv&pid_pppp#aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#{gggggggg-gggg-gggg-gggg-gggggggggggg}`

I am using the function `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` to obtain the volume name by parsing the device interface path as reported [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa364994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it seems that this feature is not working for USB devices.

Any idea of how to get the volume name from the device path in case of working with usb devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//First get GUID
guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME
//and get handle for Device information.

hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, NULL, NULL,DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE|DIGCF_PRESENT); // Get device Information handle for Volume interface

//After that loop through SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces() and you will get the usb drive storage volume path

    for(dwIndex = 0; ;dwIndex ++) // Loop until device interfaces are found.
    { 
        ZeroMemory(&devInterfaceData, sizeof(devInterfaceData));
        devInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(devInterfaceData);

        if(!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &guid,dwIndex,&devInterfaceData))// Get device Interface data.
        {
            break;
        }
        ZeroMemory(&devInfoData, sizeof(devInfoData));
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

        pDevDetail = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)buffer;
        pDevDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);



        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo,&devInterfaceData,pDevDetail,BUFFER_SIZE,&dwRequiredSize,&devInfoData); // SP_DEVINFO_DATA

        CM_Get_Parent(&devInstParent,devInfoData.DevInst, 0); // Get the device instance of parent. This points to USBSTOR.
        CM_Get_Device_ID(devInstParent, buf, BUFFER_SIZE,0);

nLength = strlen(pDevDetail->DevicePath);
            pDevDetail->DevicePath[nLength] = '\\';
            pDevDetail->DevicePath[nLength+1] = 0;  

if(GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(pDevDetail->DevicePath, volume,BUFFER_SIZE))
            {   
//Here you will get the volume corresponding to the usb
}
```

Comment: I managed to get it work some months ago but that solution is working good as well, and better optimized than mine. Thanks.